# Get an empty png image using socket in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, sockets, io

I try to transmit an image from a client to the server,
but it only worked for connection but sending image.

This is the code for the client:

```
import socket

host = '10.10.40.22'
port = 8888
address = (host, port)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

    #connect to the server
    s.connect(address)

    print('start send image')
    with open('doge.png', 'rb') as imgfile:
        while True:
            imgData = imgfile.readline(1024)
            if not imgData:
                break
            s.send(imgData)

print('end')
```

and here is the code for the server:

```
host = '10.10.40.22'
port = 8888
address = (host, port)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(address)
s.listen(1)

print('wait for connection...')

conn, addr = s.accept()

    #start to receive picture
with open('Pictures/doge.png', 'wb') as imgfile:
    while True:
        img_data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not img_data:
            break
        imgfile.write(img_data)
        print('writing ...')

conn.close()
s.close()
print('end')
```

notice that I  print a debug message in the code of server that
if it writes any bytes into the image then print the message 'writing'

how can I do now?

Comment: What output do you get? Is 10.10.40.22 a valid IP address on your system? Is "Pictures/doge.png" a valid path?

Comment: I can successfully run your client and server with the following changes: on server: host to an ampty string (i.e. INADDR_ANY) and file path to "doge.png"; on client: host to '127.0.0.1.'.

Comment: @arghol thanks! I solved it through your way and changed the ip address for the client to 127.0.0.1